# What bicycle maker is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Trying to figure out this logo. Looks like an a and a w

[image]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the head tube badge?  That's often the best way of getting an ID

Comment: The logo on the red stem looks somewhat similar too.